# What do dollar, at-sign and semicolon characters in Perl parameter lists mean?

Tags: perl, parameters

I have encountered a number of Perl scripts in the codebase at my job. Some of them contain subroutines with the following syntax oddity:

```
sub sum($$$) {
    my($a,$b,$m)=@_;
    for my $i (0..$m) {
        $$a[$i] += $$b[$i] if $$b[$i] > 0;
    }
}

sub gNode($$;$$) {
    my($n,$l,$s,$d) = @_;
    return (
            "Node name='$n' label='$l' descr='$d'" ,
            $s ? ("Shape type='$s' /") : (),
            '/Node'
        );
}

sub gOut($$@) {
    my $h = shift;
    my $i = shift;
    if ($i > 0) {
        print $h (('')x$i, map '<'.$_.'>', @_);
    } else {
        print $h map '<'.$_.'>', @_;
    }
}
```

Leaving aside the question of what these subroutines are meant to do (I'm not entirely sure myself...), what do the sequences of characters in the 'parameter list' position mean? Viz. the `$$$`, `$$;$$` and `$$@` sequences in these examples.

I have a very limited understanding of Perl, but I believe that the `my($a,$b,$m)=@_;` line in the first example (`sum`) unpacks the parameters passed to the subroutine into the `$a`, `$b` and `$m` local variables. This suggests that the `$$$` indicates the arity and type signature of `sum` (it expects three scalars, in this case). This would potentially suggest that `gOut` expects two scalars and an array. Is this the correct interpretation?

Even if the above interpretation is correct, I'm lost as to the meaning of the semicolon in the second routine (`gNode`).

Comment: Those symbols generally mean that the code was written by someone who didn't really know what they were doing. Perl prototypes are only really useful in a small number of cases. And these aren't any of those cases. See http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=861966

Comment: The Perl Monks node referenced by [Dave Cross](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7231/dave-cross) in the previous [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006898/what-do-dollar-at-sign-and-semicolon-characters-in-perl-parameter-lists-mean#comment26344863_18006898) is [Far More Than Everything You've Ever Wanted to Know about
Prototypes in Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=861966).  It should be compulsory reading for anyone who plans to use prototypes in Perl.  You only need to read it once because you won't be planning to use prototypes in Perl after you've read it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See [perldoc perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes) entry on *Prototypes*.

```
 # Declared as            Called as
 sub mylink ($$)        mylink $old, $new
 sub myvec ($$$)        myvec $var, $offset, 1
 sub myindex ($$;$)     myindex &getstring, "substr"
 sub mysyswrite ($$$;$) mysyswrite $buf, 0, length($buf) - $off, $off
 sub myreverse (@)      myreverse $a, $b, $c
 sub myjoin ($@)        myjoin ":", $a, $b, $c
 sub mypop (+)          mypop @array
 sub mysplice (+$$@)    mysplice @array, 0, 2, @pushme
 sub mykeys (+)         mykeys %{$hashref}
 sub myopen (*;$)       myopen HANDLE, $name
 sub mypipe (**)        mypipe READHANDLE, WRITEHANDLE
 sub mygrep (&@)        mygrep { /foo/ } $a, $b, $c
 sub myrand (;$)        myrand 42
 sub mytime ()          mytime
```

Don't forget: ***This is all very powerful, of course, and should be used only in moderation to make the world a better place.***

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the rest: don't use sub prototypes unless you know what you're doing. *"With great power comes great responsibility."* Those look like they were created by someone used to C prototypes. For example, the sub `sum` really should have this prototype:

```
sub sum (\$\$\$) {
```